# How to use Fetch.getResponseBody for java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I get body for getResponseBody. getMapper does not have access.

Can you give me an example?

Sorry, the stackoverflow editor restricts me from providing too much code

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
devTools = driver.getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();

RequestPattern[] requestPatterns;
requestPatterns = new RequestPattern[]{ new RequestPattern(
        Optional.of("*"),
        Optional.of(ResourceType.SCRIPT),
        Optional.of(RequestStage.RESPONSE)) };

devTools.send(new Command("Fetch.enable", ImmutableMap.of(
        "patterns", requestPatterns,
        "handleAuthRequests", true
)));

devTools.addListener(Fetch.requestPaused(), requestPaused -> {
    Command<Fetch.GetResponseBodyResponse> code = Fetch.getResponseBody(requestPaused.getRequestId());
    code.getMapper()
});
```

Comment: "the stackoverflow editor restricts me from providing too much code" -- That probably means you should explain in more detail and indicate what you have tried so far (along with logcat if you're getting any errors that you cannot solve by searching online).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to get the response body.

**Code:**

```
 devTools.addListener(Fetch.requestPaused(), requestPaused -> {
       System.out.println("Response Body: \n" + devTools.send(Fetch.getResponseBody(requestPaused.getRequestId())).getBody() + "\n");

 });
```

**Note: Please provide your exact requirements with example.**